# Why is this assembly a temporary asp.net dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I have precompiled my web site project into a single dll for the whole site. When I run a page and look at:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType())
```

It is resolving as : App_Web_qgqyxtge

But when I make a call to:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

This resolves to :

> Upload, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

I'm struggling to see why the assembly of the page I am looking at looks like a temporary asp.net dll and not the compiled dll that seems to be executing the current code?

Comment: I'm not sure so just a comment, not an answer... Is it perhaps because of the way it compiles the .aspx gets compiled at runtime? I assume your precompile is of all the .cs pages in the site but that the .aspx gets compiled into a temporary dll at runtime. I've not done much with looking at assemblies like this though so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because you are using a Web Site project in contrast to Web Application project and all classes stored in your `App_Code` folder will automatically be compiled into temporary assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the page in debug mode when you print out that message.
The compilation model is different between release and debug.
In deug there is on assembly pr page, so I would guess your page is called "Upload.aspx"